# How to hide telnet connection logs from getting printed in screen

Tags: linux, bash, shell, telnet

I have a script which telnet to remote system & user can interact with remote system. But i want to hide telnet connection logs  from getting printed for security reasons. I tried all the redirection techniques like (> , 1>, 2>), but my purpose is not served.  "1>" is not allowing to interact with remote system.

How to redirect/hide only telnet connection logs (or first 3 connection lines) below & make telnet session interactive ?

---

script :

```
#!/bin/bash  
telnet 1.2.3.4 7777
```

**sample issue execution :**

```
~/redirect.sh  
Trying 1.2.3.4...    //   redirect  
Connected to 1.2.3.4.      
Escape character is '^]'.  
login:
```

**sample expected execution :**

```
~/redirect.sh    
login:
```

Comment: for what kind of "security reasons"?

Comment: If security is of concern, use `ssh`.  Telnet is not secure at all (and is blocked in all environments I worked in).

Comment: @pynexj it displays ip address of remote server. Also these prints are not important to user.

Comment: What's the prompt on the remote system?

Answer (score 0):

There is no easy fix for this, as those three lines are simply `printf()` in the code. It would be a great deal of effort to remove those lines and allow interactive connections.

However, it is a simple client side change to modify the telnet client source and recompiling:

- Download inetutils-2.3 [from here](https://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/inetutils/).
- Extract with `tar -xJvf inetutils-2.3.tar.xz`.
- `cd inetutils-2.3`.
- `./configure`
- Use the patch in this answer: `patch telnet/commands.c < /path/to/telnet.patch`
  patching file telnet/commands.c
- `make`

Then test:

```
2>/dev/null ./telnet/telnet 192.168.100.1 22
SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_8.6
```

Copy this version of telnet into your PATH somewhere. Possibly rename it `stelnet`.

Comment: This solution works but if any option is there from script/client that will be better. Server side changes is the last option,